# set waypoint if statement if cannot access body element

Tags: javascript

I created this function to set a waypoint to fire if the following conditions are met. however on the main build I cannot access it like this due to it being built with Angular and the "header" section stays the same, so the body id and class cannot be changed.

I tried adding a div with the id="home" currently associated with the body tag but this does not work. any ideas how i could solve this dilemma?

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
function myWayPoint() {
// Search form stick to top using waypoints.js
  if(windowWidth > 768 && $('body').attr('id') == 'home'){
    var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
      element: $('.thm-search')[0],
      offset:  54
    });
  }
}
myWayPoint();
```

Comment: have you defined `windowWidth` on your own? If not, you'd have to use `window.innerWidth`

Comment: yes windowWidth is a global variable i have defines, sorry i'll amend code

Answer (score -1):

Try like this.

```
<div id="home"></div>
```

Replace `$('body').attr('id')` WIth

```
$("body").find('div').attr('id')
```

JS

```
function myWayPoint() {
// Search form stick to top using waypoints.js
  if(window.innerWidth; > 768 && $("body").find('div').attr('id') == 'home'){
    var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
      element: $('.thm-search')[0],
      offset:  54
    });
  }
}
myWayPoint();
```

Comment: like I said in the description, I have tried putting the id on a div, does not work.

Comment: not `('body').attr('id')`.it should be `$('div').attr('id')`.

Comment: OR just find div inside body like this...`$("body").find('div').attr('id')`